# "Missing Operating System" after installing Ubuntu 12.04 from a CD on a Macbook Pro

Tags: 12.04, boot, mac

I followed this guide to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my Macbook Pro 8,2 (late 2011):
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation

I used a CD.

I synced the partition table on rEFIt, and it went fine.

I do have an icon to boot on Linux, but when I launch it, after a few seconds I have "Missing Operating System" displayed, and that's all...

How can I fix that?

The only thing I see is, in the guide, it is mentioned this:

> On the last dialog of the installer, be sure to click the “Advanced”
>   button and choose to install the boot loader (grub) to your root
>   Ubuntu partition, for example /dev/sda3. This will be the only
>   partition with the EXT4 file system.

In Ubuntu 12.04 installation process, there is not such an option, but there is a dropdown menu to select where the grub bootloader should be installed.
It was /dev/sda by default, but I selected my root Ubuntu partition (in my case, /dev/sda5). I got a warning message (but actually, it was the same warning message even when I selected /dev/sda), and I continued the installation...

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Before installing Ubuntu uninstalled the other SO?

Comment: OK, I finally got it working by following this guide:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1908210

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like an issue with Grub, since I don't have a Mac and other UEFI system implementations seem to differ a lot I can just give you a heads up to this wiki page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that the guide can be well-adapted for a dual-boot issue (MacOS/Ubuntu) by removing the windows option for each step that would require to add it.

It worked fine for me (MacOS 10.7.5/Ubuntu 12.04).

Answer (score 0):

If you check this link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting#Caution_for_Mac_owners , you will find out that the installer is corrupted for mac owners:

> Caution for Mac owners
>
> In Ubuntu 11.04 (x86_64 only), due to bug 774089, the ISO CD supports
>   UEFI booting and the Ubuntu installer will try to set up the
>   bootloader for (U)EFI boot. But the installer formats the EFI System
>   Partition to FAT16 (even if the filesystem is non-empty) and also uses
>   efibootmgr, therefore Intel Macs may fail to boot due to corrupted
>   firmware. This feature is not recommended on Mac models because it can
>   corrupt the firmware. You will need to reflash the firmware to repair
>   it. The bug was fixed in Ubuntu 11.10.
>
> On Macs use only the Mac alternate ISO CD

I had the same problem and I had to use the alternate ISO CD to install Ubuntu .